# Odoo 14 - I cannot see the amount in words in a report

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

When I want to add the amount in words in a report it does not show anything. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Levi

Answer (score 0):

You have the field for amount in word?You can change your language.

```html
amount_words = fields.Char(
        'Amount in Words:',
        help="The invoice total amount in words is automatically                                  
        generated by the system..few languages are supported            
        currently",
        compute='_compute_num2words')
def _compute_num2words(self):
  self.amount_words = (num2words(
                    self.amount_total, lang='en')).upper()
```